# How do you render an object that's behind a shadow catcher?

Tags: hdri, shadowcatcher

I have a model, a hdri, a cube surrounding the model for a flat colour background, and a shadow catcher. But the shadow catcher doesn't show the cube behind it, and just shows the hdri through it.

Answer (score 0):

go into render settings>film>transparent

Comment: That works if I want to add a background afterwards, I guess. It seemed to still have some opacity on the shadowcatcher though, you can still see the edges of it.